# Looping through a plist containing an array of dictionaries

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4, nsdictionary

I have a plist containing an array with three elements all of which are dictionaries. These dictionaries contain four items each (latitude, longitude, title, subtitle). I want to loop through each of the elements and get the latitude and longitude (both of which are attributes of the dictionary).

The following code is used.

```
    - (void)loadAnnotations{

    //retrieve path of plist file and populate relevant types with its information
    NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Places1" ofType:@"plist"];
    branchList = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

     NSLog(@"hi inside method",branchList.lastObject);

    self.branchList =[NSMutableArray array];
    //code ok until this
   for (NSDictionary *key in branchList)
 {    NSLog(@"hi in loop");

        PlaceFinderAnnotation *placeAnnotations = [[PlaceFinderAnnotation alloc] init];  
        //loop through annotations array, creating parking annotations filled with the information found in the plist

            CLLocationDegrees latitude = [[key valueForKey:@"latitude"]floatValue];
            CLLocationDegrees longitude = [[key valueForKey:@"longitude"]floatValue];
            placeAnnotations.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);

            [self.branchList addObject:placeAnnotations];
            [placeAnnotations release]; placeAnnotations= nil;
            objectForKey:@"subtitle"]];

        }
    }
```

The problem is it doesnt go into the loop. meaning it doesnt print out the log command "hi inside the looppp".

Comment: If this is your entire code, it is definitely broken. If it's not your entire code, you're not doing yourself any favors by leaving parts out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume this code succeeded (we have to assume because you don't appear to be checking to make sure). Let's also assume (because you don't say) "branchList" is an instance variable in the current class:

```
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Places1" ofType:@"plist"];
branchList = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

This hopefully leaves you with an array. You could of course eliminate the "hopefully" by ... checking to make sure it leaves you with an array ( `if (branchList)...` ). Then, since "branchList" seems to be an instance variable, you immediately blow it away by replacing it with an empty array (using an accessor rather than setting it directly as you did above):

```
self.branchList =[NSMutableArray array];
```

...so then you try to iterate an empty loop (so the `NSLog()` statement is never executed).

Answer (score 0):

```
self.branchList =[NSMutableArray array];
```

creates an empty array and that is what the for statement is asked to loop through.

Delete that statement.

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Places1" ofType:@"plist"];
self.branchList = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSLog(@"hi inside method",branchList.lastObject);

for (NSDictionary *key in self.branchList) {
    NSLog(@"hi inside loopppp");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if([branchlist count]){
    for (NSDictionary *key in self.branchList) {
           NSLog(@"Key item in branchlist %@",key);
    }
}else{
     NSLog(@"There is no items in branchlist");
}
```

Comment: Interestingly the if statement is more complicated that it needs to be, just use: `if([branchlist count])`.  If `branchlist` is nil `[branchlist count]` will return 0.

Comment: Oops. in hurry i forgot to complete the condition. i have edited my answer [branchlist count] to [branchlist count]>0. so if that list has more than 0 element then it should iterate.

Comment: Still only need: `if([branchlist count])` In Obj-C sending messages to nil is allowed and has defined behavior.

Comment: If *all* that's being done is the for loop, then there's no need for a check. Whether branchList is nil or an empty array, the for statement will be evaluated and its body skipped. Adding an extra check just for the for statement is an extra statement that adds nothing to the code.

Comment: Also, this isn't the OP's problem. The problem is he's immediately assigning an empty array to the pointer that held his loaded PLIST contents.